Find the mistake - Sum and opposite of characters
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind. Please, find the mistake in the following reasoning.
The point-wise sum of two characters of a group is still the character of the group (the one associated to the direct sum of the corresponding KG-modules). Furthermore, the point-wise opposite of a character of a group is still a character of the group (the one associated to gv := -gv). Then the sum of a character and its opposite, i.e. the constantly zero function, is a character, which is absurd since characters have non-zero values.

The error is in the statement about the opposite of a character.
$g. v = -gv$ does not define an action because $$g.h.v = -g(h.v) = -g(-hv) = ghv \neq -ghv = (gh).v$$

Let me get this right. Does this have to do with the fact that, although the opposite of an automorphism of a vector space is still an automorphism, the endofunction of the automorphism group associating each of them to its opposite its not an endomorphism?

Yes, that's right
